# INSTALLING POSTFIX: VDA patch

Tags: postfix, patch

I am trying to install the VDA POSTFIX patch on a server (http://vda.sourceforge.net/) without success.
I downloaded it:

```
    wget http://vda.sourceforge.net/VDA/postfix-vda-v13-2.10.0.patch
cd postfix-2.11.0
patch -p1 < ../postfix-vda-v13-2.10.0.patch
```

I have a file which look like this:

```
root@server01:/usr/src# ls
postfix-2.11.0            postfix_2.11.0.orig.tar.gz
postfix_2.11.0-1.diff.gz  postfix-vda-v13-2.10.0.patch
postfix_2.11.0-1.dsc      README_FILES
root@server01:/usr/src#
```

when I try:

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

I get:

```
tail: cannot open ‘debian/changelog’ for reading: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: tail of debian/changelog gave error exit status 1
```

What I am doing wrong?